# jQuery hasClass vs hide

Tags: jquery, performance

For my question i'll need to first write some css.

```
.hide { display: none; }
```

Now, in jQuery which of the two examples below would be faster?

```
if ($('#a').is(':hidden')) {
    $('#a').show();
} else {
    $('#a').hide();
}
```

or

```
if ($('#a').hasClass('hide')) {
    $('#a').removeClass('hide');
} else {
    $('#a').addClass('hide');
}
```

Comment: Why don't you benchmark them at jsperf.com? I also suggest you try `.toggle()` and `.toggleClass()`, they're probably faster than either of them.

Comment: Wouldn't make a difference from user's perspective. But, I would say 1st one would be faster because everything is based on ID selector. While in second case you are using both ID and Class selector. IDs are much faster than Classs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manipulations with classes are faster than calling show/hide functions.

Here is the jsperf: http://jsperf.com/hide-or-class

Comment: Thats great! I never knew about jsperf.

Comment: +1 and just added other snippets to make sure: http://jsperf.com/hide-or-class/2 (seems like keeping a local variable is a good idea).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this code :

```
$('a').toggleClass('hide')
```

It makes the same thing that your codes but it is smaller. You can have a look to the [documentation of the toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 0):

what Lucas Willems told is correct. use toggleClass() function to reduce your code and it will much faster than using hide() and show() methods